# What do we call "easily readable books"?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, books

I just wonder if there is a good expression to refer to an "easily readable book", like a simple short story or pocket book?

Comment: When we were young, we called them "railway station books." We would buy them at the train station before long journeys here in India. (Long journeys could last anywhere between one and three days.)

Comment: 'Light reading' or 'Light viewing' refers to something read or viewed without striving for a deep understanding or study of the material

Comment: I call them "easy reads." Like, _The Cat Who_ books are an easy read.

Comment: I've heard them referred to as "easy readers". Also "chapter books".

Answer (score 2):

Consider a ["**Digest**"](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Digest-sized) (from Digest-sized)

> Digest size is a magazine size, smaller than a conventional or
>   "journal size" magazine but larger than a standard paperback book,
>   approximately 5½ x 8¼ inches, but can also be 5⅜ x 8⅜ inches and 5½ x
>   7½ inches. These sizes have evolved from the printing press
>   operation end. Some printing presses refer to digest-size as a
>   "**catalog size**," such as that used by Avon Products when selling house
>   to house. The digest format was considered to be a convenient size for
>   readers to tote around or to leave on the coffee table within easy
>   reach.

The most famous digest-sized magazine is **Reader's Digest**, from which the size appears to have been named.

Also, consider [**digestible**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/digestible) *adj.*

> (of information) easy to understand or follow.

Answer (score 2):

**Abridged**

> verb
>   (often as adjective abridged) Shorten (a book, film, speech, etc.) without losing the sense:
>   *an abridged text of his speech*
>   [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abridge)

I have seen abridged versions of lots of longer books such as Sherlock Holmes books that have been abridged to make them more appropriate for a younger more modern audience. 
However this probably doesn't apply to shorter books that have been written as simple books. I would call those '*light reading*' or '*easy reading*'.

Answer (score 1):

What about **pulp fiction**? The term referring to fiction that was printed en mass, for consumption by a wide target audience. "Pulp" referring to the cheap paper it was printed on, to further facilitate the cost of mass-production.

And no, [not the movie](http://www.vintagelibrary.com/pulpfiction/introduction/What-Is-Pulp-Fiction.php)!

Comment: Answers should *explain*, not just *tell*, for instance by excerpting a dictionary definition or providing examples. Otherwise, I would need to downvote, as not all "easily readable books" can be classified as *pulp fiction*; the cheap self-help books, celebrity memoirs, and business guides sold in the same places wouldn't necessarily qualify, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Every Book is readable in its own ways, it is whether we are worth of it or not ? Well, some books I found myself worth of were these ,

(starting from YA) Divergent Series
The Fault in our Stars
The hunger games series
Percy Jackson books are brilliant
Maze runner, of course
Alchemist (an all age book, actually)
Vampire Academy Series
The trylle trilogy by Amanda Hocking
Will Grayson, Will Grayson
The perks of being a Wallflower
The book Thief
( now the classics)

Pride and Prejudice
Moking bird
heart of darkness (to be honest, I did not read the entire book but only a short history on https://freebooksummary.com/achebe-heart-of-darkness-summary-12940
Diary of Anne Frank ( not a classic, but)
Moby Dick
The great gatsby
( The mystery)

Dan Brown books
Sydney Sheldon Books
Robert Ludlum Books
Agatha Christie
and anything else you like, these are a few, read
personally I don`t have

Answer (score 0):

A **novella**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/novella) (sometimes called a novelette).

> 2. A short novel.